# JSP request is not pass to another jsp page when using jquery load method

Tags: jquery, jsp, load, request

I encountered a problem when using jquery's load() method in JSP page. In the first page, I am trying to set attribute list1 into request and use load() to load contents of page 2 into page 1's "#content".

```
<% 
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    request.setAttribute("list1", list1);
%>

<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup( {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#RSSList').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#RSSList').show();
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#RSSList').show();
                }
            });
            var refreshId = setInterval(    
                            function() { 
                              $("#content").load("page2.jsp");
                            }, 9000); 
        } );
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
<img src="images/loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
```

In second page, list1 is being retrieved from request and do some processing before being output by out.println()

```
<% 
    ArrayList<String> list2 = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("list1");

    // process list2 here

    if (list2==null){
        out.println("list2 is null");
    } else {
        // out.println() contents of list2
    }
%>
```

Then here is where the problem lies. `request.getAttribute("list1")` in page 2 returns null pointer, and after some research I found that request is not being sent to page 2 so I cannot retrieve "list1" from request.

I cannot use `request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward(request, response)` in page 1 as it will redirect me to page2.jsp, that is not what I intended to do.

Is there any work around that I can pass request to page 2 so that I can retrieve list1 in page2.jsp? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wrap it in `doc ready`:

```
$(function(){
   $("#content").load("page2.jsp");
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that all the JSP code in page2.jsp will be loaded into page1.jsp in "content"?

Comment: But the problem here is that page2.jsp couldn't get list1 for additional processing before output as HTML

Comment: in your question it seems that you want to load `jsp2` into `jsp1`